# Mail notifications blocked by spam bad configuration

Tags: email-server

I've a new VPS, and since then I haven't been able to send email notifications. At first the port 25 for outbound traffic was blocked, now it is ok. But my ip was added to a black list, with this reason:

```
CBL Lookup Utility
IP Address xx.xx.xx.xx is listed in the CBL. It shows signs of being
infected with a spam sending trojan, malicious link or some other form of botnet.
It was last detected at 2016-11-08 03:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes), approximately 10 
hours ago.
This IP address is HELO'ing as "localhost.localdomain" 
which violates the relevant standards (specifically: RFC5321).
The CBL does not list for RFC violations per-se. This _particular_  behaviour, 
however, correlates strongly to spambot infections. 
In other words, out of thousands upon thousands of IP 
addresses HELO'ing this way, all but a handful are infected 
and spewing junk. Even if it isn't an infection, it's a misconfiguration that 
should be fixed, because many spam filtering mechanisms 
operate with the same rules, and it's best to fix it 
regardless of whether the CBL notices it or not.
DO NOT TELNET TO YOUR SERVER TO SEE WHAT IT SAYS.
Telnet will show you the banner, not the HELO."
```

So in the maillog I have something like this:

```
(mxeue002) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554-IP
  address is black listed. 554 For explanation visit
```

When I telnet the server, I get:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
```

The provider is 1and1. I have full root control in the server.

Comment: Give your server a name, reboot it, and then submit your IP to be delisted.

Comment: what type of name? a domain name? or any name? if any name, why is the localhost.localdomain, not valid?

Comment: It should be a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: will that mean that I could be only sending emails as @mydomain ? because I have multiple domains on that server